# How to insert selected value from select option using checkbox in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox, pdo, dropdown, select-options

how to insert select option value in database using checkbox?When I click checkbox and click enroll button ,select option doesn't inserting selected value.I have 3 options(Regular,Retake,Recourse) in "examtype" table but when I choose more than one subject select option not working perfectly. Here is my code...
[here is my select option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aoEn.png)

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['enroll']))
{
if (!empty($_POST['chk1'])) 
{
  if (isset($_POST['et']))
  {
    $roll_no = $_SESSION['roll_no'];
    //$selectbox1 = $_POST['et'];
  
foreach($_POST['chk1'] as $checkbox1)
{
foreach($_POST['et'] as $selectbox1)
//for($i=0;$i<sizeof($selectbox1);$i++)

$values = explode("|" , $checkbox1);
 $values1= explode("|" , $selectbox1);
$course_id= $values[0];
$semester= $values[1];
$course_name= $values[2];
$selectbox1=$values1[0];

$sql="INSERT INTO pendingcourse(roll_no,course_id,semester,course_name,exam_type,status) VALUES('$roll_no','$course_id','$semester','$course_name','$selectbox1',0)";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$checkbox1='';
$selectbox1='';
}
header("location:coursetable.php");
}
}
}
?>



 <form action="coursetable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="container mt-3" >
    <div class="accordion mb-4" id="accordionExample" >
        <div class="accordion-item" style="background-color: rgb(0, 225, 255);">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed fw-bold" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="background: #AAFFA9;">
              1st Semester
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" >
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered border-primary text-center">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col-1">Course Id</th>
                        <th scope="col-1">Semester</th>
                        <th scope="col-7">Course</th>
                        <th scope="col-1">Exam Type</th>
                        <th scope="col-1">Select</th>
                        <th scope="col-2">Result</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                 
<?php
$stmt = $connect->query("SELECT course_id,semester,course_name FROM coursetable Where semester = '1st' ");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $course_id = $row['course_id'];
  $semester = $row['semester'];
  $course_name = $row['course_name'];

?>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row"> <?php echo $course_id?></td>
                        <td > <?php echo $semester ?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $course_name ?></td>
                        <td>

                        <select name="et[]"  class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                        <?php 
                              $stmt1 = $connect->query("SELECT * from examtype");
                              $rows1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                              foreach($rows1 as $row1) {
                         ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $row1['exam_type']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['exam_type']; ?></option>
                         <?php 
                            }
                          ?>
                        </select>
                        </td>  
                        <td>     
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="<?php echo $row['course_id']?>|<?php echo $row['semester']?>|<?php echo $row['course_name']?>|<?php echo $row1['exam_type']?>">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                            </label>  
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>                     
 <?php
}
?>
                    </tbody> 
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 offset-md-5 mb-3">
    
    <button type="submit" name="enroll" class="btn btn-warning mt-2">Enroll</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work? Also, be warned that your INSERT query is widely open for SQL injection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['enroll']))
{
if (!empty($_POST['chk1'])) 
{
  if (!empty($_POST['et'])) 
{
    $roll_no = $_SESSION['roll_no'];

    $selectbox1 = $_POST['et'];
    $selectbox11=implode(',',array_filter($selectbox1));
    
    
 
    
    $i=0; 
foreach($_POST['chk1'] as $checkbox1)
{

  $selectbox111 = array_diff(explode(",", $selectbox11),array(""));
  $selectbox1111  = $selectbox111[$i];

$values = explode("|" , $checkbox1);
$course_id= $values[0];
$semester= $values[1];
$course_name= $values[2];


$sql="INSERT INTO pendingcourse(roll_no,course_id,semester,course_name,exam_type,status) VALUES('$roll_no','$course_id','$semester','$course_name','$selectbox1111',0)";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$checkbox1='';
$i++;
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do **never** use string concatenation to build SQL queries. Like: never.

Answer (score 0):

Place the input field inside a form and add
enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: hey arun,thanks for your response.I add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag but that didn't work.

Comment: A. It is not valid HTML nor XHTML

In the official W3C XHTML specification, Section B. "Element Prohibitions", states that:

"form must not contain other form elements."

Comment: I remove the other form tag from my code.still nothing happen

Comment: sure,I think the problem is with the foreach loop

Comment: can i know the exact idea you are trying to implement.why you want to select and tick something .With selection itself we can acheive the same result.Can you explain more about the idea implemented here

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should `enctype="multipart/form-data"` be needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="et[]"  class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" multiple>
```

try this

add multiple in select

Comment: I tried that also...didn't solve the issue